# Avoid merge commit in git

Tags: git, merge, rebase

My local repo was looking like that before I had to pull:

```
[my commit 3] <- to be pushed
[my commit 2] <- already pushed
[my commit 1]
```

So I pulled and had to do a merge because there were conflicts, which I commited locally:

```
[merge commit] <- created that by resolving conflicts
[new commit from coworker] <- pulled that
[my commit 3]
[my commit 2]
[my commit 1]
```

Now my questions is how I can get rid of the merge commit at the top. I think it should look like that:

```
[my commit 3]
[new commit from coworker] 
[my commit 2]
[my commit 1]
```

How can I rebase like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `git pull`, do `git pull --rebase`.

(You can `git reset --hard [my commit 3]` to get back to where you were before the pull, then do `git pull --rebase`.)

Comment: This works great, but isnt there any way I can do this by hand? I tried to rebase but it seems like I can only rebase my own commits?

Comment: You have to rebase your commit on top of your coworker's change. E.g. `git fetch`, then `git rebase [new commit from coworker]` to put your commit on top of theirs.